# PostgreSQL Error “canceling statement due to statement timeout”

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, knex.js

I get this error a lot of times when trying to make a simple GET request that is supposed to fetch thousands of entries (eventually tens of thousands).

Is there some sort of threshold or better way to fetch thousands of rows of data at once?

Here is my fetch request...

```
export async function getAllAssets() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(BASE_URL + "assets", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const jsonResponse = await response.json(); //json-ify readablestream data
    if (jsonResponse) 
    {
      return jsonResponse;
    }
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e, "Failed to fetch all assets.");
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Well, change the PostgreSQL parameter `statement_timeout`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry, do I do this with an actual query, or as part of the query (the batchInsert), or do I have to figure out how to make this part of my server code?

Like something like this?

const pg = require('pg');
pg.statement_timeout = 150000;

Comment: I don't speak JavaScript. First, figure out if the limit is set in the configuration of the database or in the configuration of your client driver. Then modify the setting.